# SPARQL Update doesn't insert with optional statements

Tags: sparql, virtuoso

I try to use the SPARQL Update query such that it will delete triples if its in the graph and afterwards insert new triples even if no delete happened.

I have this query as example in the Virtuoso SPARQL endpoint after creating the graph http://example.de/:

```
WITH <http://example.de/>
DELETE {
  <http://example.de/Rheinmetall+AG> 
                  <http://dbpedia.org/property/locationStreet> 
                                    ?0 .
}
INSERT {
  <http://example.de/Rheinmetall+AG> 
                  <http://dbpedia.org/property/locationStreet> 
                                    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Rheinmetall+Platz+1> .
}
WHERE
  { OPTIONAL
      { <http://example.de/Rheinmetall+AG>
                  <http://dbpedia.org/property/locationStreet>  
                                    ?0
      }
  }
```

It doesn't insert any triples:

```
Modify <http://example.de/>, delete 0 (or less) and insert 0 (or less) triples -- done
```

If I leave the `WHERE` clause empty it will insert one triple. And afterwards the original query will also delete and insert one triple.
But I also want it to work if the triple is not in the graph yet. Is it possible to overcome that problem in an update query or do I have to call delete and insert separately?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: it would be possible but I don't understand why. You can also put multiple SPARQL update statements into a single request, usually comma separated. Did you try this? Just do `INSERT DATA` for the triple that you always want to add. And then `;` and then `DELETE ... WHERE` statement

Comment: and the `OPTIONAL` didn't work because it's basically a left-join on an empty table

Comment: The reason it works in the default graph and not in the WITH case is rooted in SPARQL Query and the definition of `GRAPH <nosuchurui> { pattern }`. See answer. The WHERE pattern of { OPTIONAL {...} } is a left-join on the unit table which is why it works in the default graph case.

Comment: @UninformedUser - I think your query order is backward. OP wants to `DELETE` all matching triples if present, and then `INSERT` one triple. Doing the `INSERT` first would mean that the triple in the `INSERT` query would then immediately be caught in the `DELETE` query.

Comment: @AndyS - The OP never tried the default graph case. The `WITH` clause is *always* present, in all described tests. The change they made is in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @Yomu - Given that you're using Virtuoso, you may get better help from the [OpenLink Community Forum](http://community.openlinksw.com/), or the [Issues area of the Github project](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/). You could answer first questions in your first post there (or a question edit, here) -- 1. Virtuoso Open Source or Enterprise Edition? 2. Version (output of `virtuoso -?`)?

Comment: Oops, left off -- 3. Can we access your SPARQL endpoint?

Comment: Due to comments being directed to the person and not the content, I have deleted this answer. Openlink like may wish to check that the described behaviour will differ as whether the graph is created first or not.

Answer (score 1):

A solution (already mentioned) is have two operations in a single request. This also means the OPTIONAL is not necessary and the `DELETE` can be a `DELETE WHERE`: `WITH DELETE {} WHERE {}` would also work.

```
DELETE WHERE { 
   GRAPH <http://example.de/> {
     <http://example.de/Rheinmetall+AG>
                  <http://dbpedia.org/property/locationStreet>  
                                    ?0
        }
   } ;

INSERT DATA { 
    GRAPH <http://example.de/> {
        <http://example.de/Rheinmetall+AG> 
                  <http://dbpedia.org/property/locationStreet> 
                                    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Rheinmetall+Platz+1>
   }
}
```